# Is it possible to define a variable in Java and use that in JSP code?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts, el

I have a drop down like below:

```
<html:select styleId="colorCodeId" property="msSpec.colorcodeId" name="Form"  styleClass="form-control">
                            <option value="-1"></option>
                            <html:optionsCollection property="colorcodeList" style="background: <%=test1%>;"/>
                        </html:select>
```

in Java code I have:

```
List<LabelValueBean> colorcodeList = new ArrayList<LabelValueBean>();
for (Mty property : customPropertyList) {
            LabelValueBean bean = new LabelValueBean(property.getName(), property.getId().toString());

if (property instanceof ColorCode) {
                test1 = property.getName();
                System.out.println("test1: " + test1);
                colorcodeList.add(bean);
            }
}
```

Is it possible I define `test1` like above and use that as a background color in my drop down? Right now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSP EL expression instead of the variable. The reason is to remove scriptlets from your code.

```
<html:select styleId="colorCodeId" property="msSpec.colorcodeId" name="Form"  styleClass="form-control" style="${test1}">
                            <option value="-1"></option>
                            <html:optionsCollection property="colorcodeList" />
                        </html:select>
```

In the action you write

```
List<LabelValueBean> colorcodeList = new ArrayList<LabelValueBean>();
for (Mty property : customPropertyList) {
            LabelValueBean bean = new LabelValueBean(property.getName(), property.getId().toString());

if (property instanceof ColorCode) {
                test1 = property.getName();
                System.out.println("test1: " + test1);
                request.setAttribute("test1", "background: "+test1+";");
                colorcodeList.add(bean);
            }

}
```

Comment: When I put request in my java code, it says request can not resolved. should I import a library?

Comment: It's available to your action.

Answer (score 0):

JSP expression language cannot make use of Java variables declared in custom Java code.

The "variables" that JSP expression language can access are actually attributes set in one of the four "scopes" that are defined by the JSP / Servlet framework; i.e. "session", "request", "page" and "application".

You can get and set these attributes from Java; e.g.

```
   // Request scope
   request.getAttribute("test1");  
   request.setAttribute("test1", someValue);
```

For more information:

- The Java EE 5 tutorial: [Using Scope Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafo.html#bnafp)

---

> When I put request in my java code, it says request can not resolved. should I import a library?

If your code is embedded in a JSP, then `request` should be declared.

Otherwise, replace `request` with the name of the variable that refers to the `HttpServletRequest` object for the current request.